# Results of a groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and learning the basic stuff by trial and error. I would like to input a string and display the group by results of the string. Just wondering how to do it. I tried below and got some error.

**Input:-**

1223452211

**Code :-**

```
from itertools import groupby
print(groupby(input()))
```

**Error:-**

```
<itertools.groupby object at 0x0000000000013980E8>
```

Comment: This isn't an error, it's the result of the call to `groupby`, which is perfectly usable: you can iterate over it or convert to a list and more.

Comment: Is there a way to print the results?

Comment: Probably a better starting point to experiment is to do: `[k, list(g) for k, g in groupby(input())]`

Comment: @Teja, you _are_ printing the result already. It's just its form that may seem confusing.

Comment: @JonClements An even better starting point would be to read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0):

you could use groupby to group elements. To use a groupby make sure a sequence is sorted. groupby takes a sorted data and then breaks it to groups where the number changes. for example [1,1,1,3,5,5,5,8] will be broken into groups [1,1,1], [3], [5,5,5],[8], these groups will have a key 1, 3, 5, 8 respectively. groupby is a iterator and the keys and groups in the iterator can be exposed using for loops or next() operator.

Here is a case where I show how to use it to group elements in a list.

```
from itertools import groupby
mylist = [1,2,5,3,3,5,1,7,8,8,3]
sorted_list = sorted(mylist)
print sorted_string
for key,group in groupby(sorted_list):
    print "elements in the group with key {}".format(key)
    for thing in group:
        print thing
    print '************'
```

this will results in

```
sorted list : [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8]

elements in the group with key 1
1
1
************
elements in the group with key 2
2
************
elements in the group with key 3
3
3
3
************
elements in the group with key 5
5
5
************
elements in the group with key 7
7
************
elements in the group with key 8
8
8
***********
```